# See if @ symbol is in field and proceed with form validation

Tags: php

I am trying to set up a web form for my website and I want to search the user's input for an @ symbol and if it is not there, the form should not validate and a message should show up asking the user to recomplete the form.

Here's what I have so far:-

```
$at = "@";
if (is_null($at[$email]))
{
return FALSE;
}
```

I hope someone can help me!

Comment: Curious, where have you found such syntax: `is_null($at[$email])`?! o_O

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$email = "someone@example.com";
if(eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email)) {  
  echo "Valid email address.";
}
else {
  echo "Invalid email address.";
}
?>
```

Or little bit more modern:

```
<?php
        $email_address = "someone@example.com";

    if (preg_match("/^[^@]*@[^@]*\.[^@]*$/", $email_address)) {
        return "E-mail address";       
    }

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I really appreciate it! The only thing is, once this is completed, the rest of the form still displays and processes...

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, in this case I suggest you use Javascript email form validator (any, google it), that will check form data before submit and will literally "alert" user to complete it right.

Comment: You can also use simple html for that: E-mail address <input type="email" name="email"> where type is set to email!

Comment: @John: PHP has a more standards-compliant email regex builtin: `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`